# Level change and trend change in the interrupted time series regression, does collinearity matters?

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis

In the interrupted time series regression, we are interested in the level change or trend change due to a policy change or an intervention event occurance. If the dates of those interventions are known, the model then can be expressed as

> <sub>y = intercept + coef.time*time(t)+coef.intervention*intervention(t)+coef.time after intervention*time(t) after intervention+error(t).</sub>

In my analysis, there is another type of intervention which is a cumulative intervention, which measures the cumulative number of people participate into the intervention program. The underlying interest is on the contribution of those people in the change of the series. Therefore there is additional variable in the model which is

```
y = ...... + coef.cumulative*number.cumulative(t)+error(t).
```

The problem is that the cumulative intervention happens in the same period of external interrupted event, say policy change.
For example, a simple simulated data

```
     t <- 1:262
     int.1 <- c(rep(0,76),rep(1,186)) #level change 
     trd.1 <- c(rep(0,76),seq(1,186)) #trend change
     int.2 <- c(rep(0,200),rep(1,62)) #level change 
     trd.2 <- c(rep(0,200),seq(1,62)) #trend change
     coef.t <- 10
     coef.int.1 <- -35
     coef.trd.1 <- -2.3
     coef.int.2 <- -25
     coef.trd.2 <- -3
     coef.gp <- -0.014
     y <- coef.t*t+coef.int.1*int.1+coef.trd.1*trd.1+
          coef.int.2*int.2+coef.trd.2*trd.2+coef.gp*cumgp
```

Someone strongly argued that there are collinearities based on correlation matrix among those variabes especially between cumgp and second intervention.

```
              t         int.1     trd.1     int.2     trd.2     cumgp

         t    1.0000000 0.7860058 0.9739927 0.7361619 0.6799093 0.7375151
     int.1    0.7860058 1.0000000 0.6840924 0.3559026 0.2983724 0.3438636
     trd.1    0.9739927 0.6840924 1.0000000 0.8000324 0.7472221 0.8049856
     int.2    0.7361619 0.3559026 0.8000324 1.0000000 0.8383540 0.9274249
     trd.2    0.6799093 0.2983724 0.7472221 0.8383540 1.0000000 0.9377249
     cumgp    0.7375151 0.3438636 0.8049856 0.9274249 0.9377249 1.0000000
```

Based on second plot above which is the true process, if say we do not recognize the second intervention, and all the contributions of change in the series go to "cumgp",

Personally I don't think it is a collinearity problem, as cumgp and second intervention contribute to the change of the series independently, but around the same time.

Therefore could any one suggest how to interpret such a problem to convince "someone"?

Comment: Your correlation matrix is ill-conditioned (the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) is 335.9, an order of magnitude larger than [values usually considered to indicate multicollinearity problems](http://www.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats2/l11.pdf)).  Because this contradicts one of your important assumptions, you might want to re-think your question.